# R package installation while running through SSIS halts giving the following error:

Tags: r, ssis, dplyr, tidytext

```
install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)
install.packages("tidytext")
library(tidytext)
install.packages("reshape")
library(reshape)
install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)
install.packages("tidyr")
library(tidyr)
install.packages("twitteR")
library(twitteR)
install.packages("tm")
library(tm)
```

This is the order in which in I have specified the packages for installation. When I try to run the script through SSIS, the following error occurs:

Error: Package or namespace load failed for 'tidytext'
There is no package called 'dplyr'

Do the packages have to be installed in a specific order? Not able to figure out the correct order.

Comment: Have you tried not calling the packages until everything is installed? i.e. Do all `install.packages`, then do all `library` calls.

Comment: tried that as well

Comment: another thing to try is all the installs in an ssis task and all the library calls in another ssis task dependent on the first one